# Fixed Parameter Algorithms

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

Suppose a parameter $\hat{k}$ is larger than another parameter $k$, assume that $k$ is bounded 
by a function $f$ of $\hat{k}$.

How can we prove that if a problem is FPT with respect to $k$ implies it is FPT w.r.to $\hat{k}$.

Answer (score 0):

Just substitute the fact $k\leq \hat{k}\leq f(k)$ into the definition of what it means for the problem to be FPT with respect to $k$.